# Is there a built-in F# function to perform a side-effect on an item and return the item

Tags: f#

When I write an F# function that looks something like this...

```
let createCollection1() =
    let c = ObservableCollection<int>()
    c.CollectionChanged.Add(onCollectionChanged)
    logInstanceCreation c
    c
```

... I *want* to do something like this...

```
let apply f a = f(a); a

let createCollection2() =
    ObservableCollection<int>()
    |> apply (fun c -> c.CollectionChanged.Add(onCollectionChanged))
    |> apply logInstanceCreation
```

My `apply` function simply performs a side-effect on an argument and then returns that argument. I know it does not make a big difference, but I like it.

Is there already a built-in F# function like my `apply` function?

**EDIT**

Thanks to John Palmer for pointing me to the duplicate question. It mentions several alternatives, including `tee` and `tap`. I like the `|>!` operator approach:

```
let inline ( |>! ) x sideEffect = sideEffect x; x

let createCollection3() =
    ObservableCollection<int>()
    |>! fun c -> c.CollectionChanged.Add(onCollectionChanged)
    |>! logInstanceCreation
```

Very nice!

Comment: The duplicate question definitely answers my question. However, a search for "site:stackoverflow.com F# function to perform side-effect" does not yield that question. A search for "site:stackoverflow.com F# function tee" yields that question. But who knows to search for "tee"? I recommend keeping this question here for the search engines.

Comment: the point of duplicates is to enable people to search for the same things in different ways.